# How to access the Session Object Inside event bus in Vertx?

Tags: vert.x

My Request handler

```
 router.route("/clientController/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
```

and my event bus is

```
eb.consumer("chat.to.server",message->{
        System.out.println("Getting Request in Client Controller Event Bus");
        JsonObject data = (JsonObject) message.body();
        String classifier = data.getString("classifier");

        if(classifier.equals("loginUri")) {
            System.out.println("Request for Login URI");
            vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                future.complete(OAuth.getOAuthParam());
            }, res -> {
                eb.publish("chat.to.client", res.result());
            });

        }
```

is it possible to access the session object inside event bus as we do the normal routing handler as routingContext.getSession()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. Routing context session is not related to the eventbus. The eventbus can be deployed without having a HTTP server while routing context is a very web specific thing.

If you need to have state on your eventbus then I'd say you need to pass the session id in your message headers, and only if the session is clustered then you might be able to retrieve it from the cluster store by id. By doing so you might also introduce inconsistency so i'd advice not to do it.

Alternative just put all your required session data in your message payload.